# Centering cell in table

Tags: tables, formatting

I'm trying centering cells in `\ toprule`. Other cells are properly formatted. I tried with `> {\ centering}` but still can't understand how to format cells properly.

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Caption}
    \begin{tabular}
            {@{}
            c
            S[table-format=1.2]
            S[table-format=2.2]
            // i tried also: c*{1}{S[table-format=2.2]}>{\centering}
            S[table-format=3.2]
            S[table-format=1.2]
            @{} }
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{m{5.335em}}{nr fragmentu} & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.165em}}{częstotliwość środkowa [GHz]} & \multicolumn{1}{m{5.72em}}{$|s_{11}|$} & \multicolumn{1}{p{6.665em}}{szer. pasma [MHz]} & \multicolumn{1}{p{6.945em}}{szer. pasma [\%]} \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{9}[2]{*}{1} & 2,40  & -18,69 & 20,90 & 0,87\% \\
          & 3,34  & -15,37 & 18,90 & 0,57\% \\
          & 3,73  & -15,77 & -5,10 & -0,14\% \\
          & 3,98  & -22,82 & 35,70 & 0,90\% \\
          & 5,32  & -12,27 & 50,40 & 0,95\% \\
          & 5,63  & -15,16 & 29,10 & 0,52\% \\
          & 5,77  & -21,04 & 56,30 & 0,98\% \\
          & 6,58  & -26,11 & 71,00 & 1,08\% \\
          & 7,64  & -30,24 & 136,30 & 1,78\% \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{4}[2]{*}{2} & 2,40  & -14,95 & 32,40 & 1,35\% \\
          & 3,42  & -10,65 & 32,90 & 0,96\% \\
          & 4,40  & -18,10 & 58,10 & 1,32\% \\
          & 7,08  & -1,18 & 56,60 & 0,80\% \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{3}[2]{*}{3} & 2,40  & -11,68 & 20,30 & 0,85\% \\
          & 3,39  & -24,96 & 64,50 & 1,90\% \\
          & 7,10  & -18,44 & 121,30 & 1,71\% \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{7}[2]{*}{4} & 1,49  & -23,37 & 28,80 & 1,93\% \\
          & 2,40  & -24,19 & 33,90 & 1,41\% \\
          & 2,79  & -25,83 & 43,70 & 1,57\% \\
          & 3,84  & -30,60 & 123,50 & 3,22\% \\
          & 4,16  & -16,74 & 69,30 & 1,66\% \\
          & 4,40  & -13,26 & 66,70 & 1,52\% \\
          & 5,97  & -34,36 & 348,70 & 5,84\% \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:Tab_iter5}%
\end{table}%
```

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: WWhat do you mean with ‘cells in \ toprule’ ?

Comment: @Bernard, Im soory, I've put image in code block. Now, check the picture in the first row of table, please.

Comment: Try `\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{5.335em}}{nr fragmentu}` etc or use \newcolumntype to define that kind of columns (`M` for example that will be centered by default) [`\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}`]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

For above table I replace  `\multicolumn{1}{m{...}}{ < content}` with `\makecell{< content>}` and manulay broke content where I like to have:

```
\documentclass[twocolumns]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Caption}
    \begin{tabular}
            {@{}
            c
            S[table-format=1.2]
            S[table-format=2.2]
            % i tried also: c*{1}{S[table-format=2.2]}>{\centering}
            S[table-format=3.2]
            S[table-format=1.2]
            @{} }
    \toprule
\makecell{nr.\\ fragmentu} 
    & {\makecell{częstotliwość\\ środkowa [GHz]}} 
        & {\makecell{$|s_{11}|$}} 
            & {\makecell{szer. pasma\\ {[MHz]}}} 
                & {\makecell{szer. pasma\\ {[\%]}}}         \\
    \midrule
\multirow{9}[2]{*}{1} 
    & 2,40  & -18,69 & 20,90 & 0,87 \\
    & 3,34  & -15,37 & 18,90 & 0,57 \\
    & 3,73  & -15,77 & -5,10 & -0,14 \\
    & 3,98  & -22,82 & 35,70 & 0,90 \\
    & 5,32  & -12,27 & 50,40 & 0,95 \\
    & 5,63  & -15,16 & 29,10 & 0,52 \\
    & 5,77  & -21,04 & 56,30 & 0,98 \\
    & 6,58  & -26,11 & 71,00 & 1,08 \\
    & 7,64  & -30,24 & 136,30 & 1,78 \\
    \midrule
\multirow{4}[2]{*}{2} 
    & 2,40  & -14,95 & 32,40 & 1,35 \\
    & 3,42  & -10,65 & 32,90 & 0,96 \\
    & 4,40  & -18,10 & 58,10 & 1,32 \\
    & 7,08  & -1,18 & 56,60 & 0,80 \\
    \midrule
\multirow{3}[2]{*}{3} 
    & 2,40  & -11,68 & 20,30 & 0,85 \\
    & 3,39  & -24,96 & 64,50 & 1,90 \\
    & 7,10  & -18,44 & 121,30 & 1,71 \\
    \midrule
\multirow{7}[2]{*}{4} 
    & 1,49  & -23,37 & 28,80 & 1,93 \\
    & 2,40  & -24,19 & 33,90 & 1,41 \\
    & 2,79  & -25,83 & 43,70 & 1,57 \\
    & 3,84  & -30,60 & 123,50 & 3,22 \\
    & 4,16  & -16,74 & 69,30 & 1,66 \\
    & 4,40  & -13,26 & 66,70 & 1,52 \\
    & 5,97  & -34,36 & 348,70 & 5,84 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:Tab_iter5}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```